# AssertionError using Apache2 and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Python 3.4)

Tags: 14.04, apache2, python3

On Ubuntu 14.04, using Apache2 with package libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed gives errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log

The way to reproduce is straightforward :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
# /var/log/apache2/error.log is "clean"
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo service apache2 restart
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log gives the following error :

```
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.641332 2015] [:error] [pid 3141:tid 140703516379008] Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.643563 2015] [:error] [pid 3141:tid 140703516379008] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.643633 2015] [:error] [pid 3141:tid 140703516379008]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.644350 2015] [:error] [pid 3141:tid 140703516379008]     assert tlock is not None
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.643449 2015] [:error] [pid 3140:tid 140703516379008] Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.644456 2015] [:error] [pid 3140:tid 140703516379008] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.644514 2015] [:error] [pid 3140:tid 140703516379008]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.645052 2015] [:error] [pid 3140:tid 140703516379008]     assert tlock is not None
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.645119 2015] [:error] [pid 3141:tid 140703516379008] AssertionError: 
[Mon Jan 05 16:51:53.647513 2015] [:error] [pid 3140:tid 140703516379008] AssertionError:
```

How to get it work error-free?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with mod_wsgi 3.4. According to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22948#comment:2 we need to use mod_wsgi version 4.2+ for Python 3.4.

The best way to install mod_wsgi to the latest version is to get it with pip (can be in virtualenv) and then install its module to apache system-wide.
In my case I use virtualenv set in `/venv_path`.

1) Remove problematic package and install dependency

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

2) Install mod_wsgi in virtualenv with pip

```
. /venv_path/bin/activate
pip install mod_wsgi
```

3) Install into Apache (system-wide)

```
sudo /venv_path/bin/mod_wsgi-express install-module
sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.load /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.conf
```

Content of `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.load`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so
```

Content of `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.conf`

```
WSGIPythonHome /venv_path
```

4) Enable the module and restart Apache.

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi_express
sudo service apache2 restart
```

5) Check that there are no errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: You may want to mention that the command to create a virtualenv is `virtualenv -p python3.4 DIRECTORY`, or for 3.4+, better: `pyvenv-3.4 DIRECTORY`.

Comment: That's correct ... but I didn't mention it to keep the focus on the mod_wsgi question.

Comment: But since you're already using virtualenv in your example, why not also mention how to create it?

Comment: If someone else gets an error (`cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`) when trying to do this, remember to switch the version in step 3. I was using Python 3.5, 64-bit. `mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. If you don't know which version you have, go to the folder (`/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`) and look.

This answer seems to be based on 32-bit python 3.4.

Comment: this method is python-version-agnostic and worked for me with python3.6 `sudo /venv_path/bin/mod_wsgi-express install-module` in step 3 will print the paths that you need to put in the `wsgi_express` files

Comment: If any one is coming across this, I followed this to successfully use apache2 and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 20.04 (ships with system python 3.8). I wanted to use a python3.9 virtualenv. However, my sys.path was still referencing python3.8 and I was hitting lots of python package conflicts. I could not seem to override or set sys.path to not use python3.8 when using libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3. However, following the above answer resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add something to the accepted answer provided by samb.

The actual lines of config that you need to add to the module config are the ones outputted by the `mod_wsgi-express install-module` command (this wasn't explicit in the accepted answer).

Also, in my case (and according to the [mod_wsgi pkg documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) - probably this wasn't the case when the accepted answer was written) I didn't get any `wsgi_express.*` files in `mods-available`, but only `wsgi.*`, and it was sufficient to replace the `wsgi.load` file with the new config by running

```
mod_wsgi-express install-module > /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
```

Of course, this would overwrite the whole file, so watch out in case you happen to have any more directives in it.