# Error remove a package which is not installed

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg

I always get a notification that: Ubuntu faced an internal error. After checking it turn out there is a package not fully installed or removed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`.

When I run: `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to use `sudo apt autoremove`. But did not fully remove it
I also did: `sudo dpkg --remove libapache-mod-wsgi-py3`
When I try to remove the package I get this:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libapache-mod-wsgi-py3 which isn't installed
```

But still having the same error. How to fix this??

Comment: Also to my knowledge remove and autoremove do not fully get rid of all files associated w a package..there are multiple locations where related files are stored when you install a package

Comment: What version(s) of python do you have

Comment: Thanks @Emily ! Then how to remove all the nested dependencies related to this package? I have Python `2.7`, `3.5`, and '3.6'

Comment: My guess is that there was a conflict with this package and the version of python it was compiled against. What's the output of `which python` and `ps -fA | grep python` ?

Comment: Anyway, since you are having problems removing the package, first I would try using Synaptic to do it. That will take care of alerting you of subpackages that need to be removed as well. Then you could do `sudo apt purge` (more thorough than remove). If you can't uninstall with synaptic or apt purge, it might be because apache is running and using (or trying to use?) the package...execute `sudo systemctl stop apache2.service` and then try again

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to delete it using `--purge` after stopping apache2 service. But I am not sure now how to check it is completely removed or not. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! As for making sure everything is gone, I know for sure there are other answers on this site that go over this in depth, with much better instructions than I gave! See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package/151943) for example. I will post my comments as an answer since it did at least get you on the right track to uninstalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1: Stop apache2 service from running

Before uninstalling enter this command into Terminal/other CLI:

`sudo systemctl stop apache2.service`

### Step 2: Remove package binaries, system-wide configuration files, and orphaned dependencies

To completely remove the package itself, along with its system-wide configuration files and any dependencies that were required by the package but no longer needed, execute:

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove <packagename>`

Explanation: `purge` does the same thing as `apt-get remove --purge`; it gets rid of the package itself and associated configuration files. It's like one step above `apt-get remove`, which only deletes the binaries. `--auto-remove` does the same thing as `apt-get autoremove`; it gets rid of orphaned dependencies.

Sorry I didn't give you that specific command to use in the comments, but it's perfectly fine to do everything using separate commands rather than one single command, since the same actions are performed. In your specific case, since you've already done `remove --purge`, you can just execute the autoremove part now with `sudo apt autoremove` and that should take care of the stuff that remove --purge didn't delete. The single-entry way is just a bit faster.

**Alternatively, if you want to be selective about what dependencies get removed**, you can get rid of the `--auto-remove` flag (executing `sudo apt-get purge <packagename>`) and follow the steps I found from this [amazing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166815/787506) to easily create a sort of custom dependency-uninstaller. The following command first lists all package dependencies, then pipes that list into individual `apt-get remove` commands, which all gets sent to a shell script that you can open in a text editor and modify as needed. Then you just execute the shell script once you're happy with it. The command is:

`apt-cache depends <packagename>|awk '{print "sudo apt-get remove "$NF}' >pg_remove.sh`

The pg_remove.sh file is saved to your home directory (obviously you can add a path before the output file name if you want to save it somewhere else). To run the script execute `bash pg_remove.sh` (again if your output file is not in your home directory, modify this command to include the path to its location).

### Step 3: Remove user configuration files

Next you have to manually remove user-specific configuration files stored in your home directory. These may be in their own directory, and/or in ~/.config, ~/.cache, ~/.local.

First look for files that contain the package name in `~/.config` and remove them. You can use `ls -a ~/.config` or `ls -A ~/.config` to see all the contents of your home, including hidden files/folders. If you're using Nautilus to do this, make sure you have enabled the option to view hidden files (`View>Show Hidden Files`). Then delete them using rm or Nautilus.

Also look in your home folder for a directory with the package name (or something that looks like the package name--it may not be exactly the same). It will probably be hidden by default, and it will probably begin with a "."--if it exists. I don't know that much about apache so I'm not sure if this directory will be there, or what it would look like. Anyway, if it exists, remove it also!

Additionally, check in `~/.cache` and `~/.local/share` for a directory named after the package.

*References for Steps 2 and 3: [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package/151943#151943), [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application), [How to remove configuration files completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20127/how-to-remove-configuration-files-completely?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)*

### Possible future reinstallation

This package may have libraries you you actually need in the future and you may need to reinstall it. Ubuntu comes with libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed, which is like a default version, so my guess is that it couldn't play nicely with whatever Python version you were using. If you want to know more check the output of `which python` and `ps -fA | grep python`...If a conflict with the Python version was indeed the problem, then [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569550/assertionerror-using-apache2-and-libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3-on-ubuntu-14-04-python) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569550/assertionerror-using-apache2-and-libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3-on-ubuntu-14-04-python/569551) address how you can properly install mod-wgsi via pip (the package pip installs is something called mod_wgsi).

Comment: @SineCo, awesome! You're welcome!